# LVDS: Higher skew deviation or termination resistors as close as possible to the IC

Tags: lvds, skew

I am designing a pcb with a video interface which runs lvds. LVDS has termination resistors and the datasheet states to have them put as close to the IC pins as possible. It's not 4k, but close to fullhd with < 200MHz of pixel clocks. Please have a look at the image:

[image]

As you can see, the four input pairs in a row have the same polarity sequence, first n then p. The single pair on the left has a different order, and I cannot change it because both ICs are on the same layer. That's why I went around the pins and came in from behind, thus changing the polarity to match the IC.

But as the datasheet states, the resistors should be as close as possible. The four resistors at the top have roughly 8mm of trace, which I could of course shorten and put the resistors directly next to the pins.

I cannot do that for the left pair.

So what's best practice in this case and why? The way I did it, with longer but matching distance?
Or reverse the polarity of the left pair somewhere else with vias, and put all five resistors next to the input pins?

Comment: Is this a camera link interface? Also, please post a link to the datasheet. The goal here is to prevent reflections. If you can add the termination close to the receiver the wave will enter the receiver around the same time as it enters the termination which minimizes reflections. If you place the termination resistor too early, you will have a high impedance discontinuity at the receiver which will cause reflections. If you can't get it close you can use fly by termination and place the resistor *after* the receiver. The extra length usually is not a cause for concern if it's not *too* long

Comment: No it's the output of a PTN3460 going to another IC, but I must not publish the datasheet. I can't find useful stuff with "fly by termination", can you elaborate? Also, concerning "too long": Right now it's 8mm, I can cut it down to 1-2mm. Is that too much difference?

Comment: Fly by just means that you bring the traces for the LVDS pair to the IC pads first, then continue on to the termination resistor.  So long as everything is controlled impedance, the distance to the termination resistor is not critical.  Though as for almost everything with LVDS, I would simulate what you finally end up with in your favorite SI tool.

Comment: And what are those 5 signals you're talking about? Are they 4 data lanes plus a clock, or something else?

Comment: Yes, if you click on the image you can see it's lvds0-3 and one with a c for clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer...

Based on the discussions above, I would move the resistor for the clock as close to the pads you can get it, and keep the resistors for the 4 data lines where they are.  This keeps everything pretty much the same for the 4 data lines, and makes the clock "better".  Then, as I said earlier, simulate.  And make sure you have the right model for the LVDS driver, and not some generic driver that comes with your SI tool.